# how to use ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString to get contents of arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, reflection

I want to get contents of arrayList using reflection, but I am only getting the arrayList object instead of arrayList values with reflectionToString. Below is the sample code and output:

```
   ArrayList<String> nodeList = new ArrayList<String>();
   nodeList.add("Inpt1");
   nodeList.add("Inpt2");
   System.out.println(ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(nodeList,  ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE));

   Output:
   java.util.ArrayList@5ca881b5[
   size=2
   ]
```

Can you tell me a way to get the contents of ArrayList with reflectionToString?

Comment: Why are you doing this? You have an `ArrayList<String>`, what's wrong with `nodeList.toString()`?

Comment: I did have work around as shown below but I didn't like my work around, I am looking for a simple solution.          if (o instanceof ArrayList) {
         
            for(int i =0; i<((ArrayList) o).size(); i++){
                Object game = ((ArrayList) o).get(i);
                System.out.println(ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(game,  ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE));
                
            }

    
        
        }

Comment: @Elliott, this is only test code, my use case requires to intercept methods using byte code instrumentation and get the object values so, I have to use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

This can be one solution. I did it for some code debugging purpose for temporary use.

```
ArrayList<String> nodeList = new ArrayList<String>();
   nodeList.add("Inpt1");
   nodeList.add("Inpt2");
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
nodeList.forEach(p -> builder.append(ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(p,  ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE)))
   System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the elements don't feature in the output is because `ArrayList#elementData` is `transient` and by default `ReflectionStringBuilder` will *not* include those.

There is an overloaded version of `reflectionToString` that will do the job you are after:

```
    reflectionToString(Object object, ToStringStyle style, boolean outputTransients)
```

Applying that method to your example (with `outputTransients=true`), I get:

```
java.util.ArrayList@3b7d3a38[
  elementData={Inpt1,Inpt2,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>,<null>}
  size=2
  modCount=2
]
```

PS: This was made fairly confusing in my ignorance, as I was testing with `Arrays.asList("a", "b")` which returns its own `ArrayList` type with element data that is *not* transient.